# VBA Worksheet(name).Calculate not working consistantly in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text box which takes user input which is referenced by a number of custom functions in VBA. I wanted the functions to recalculate everytime the input in the text box is changed. The text box input represents a scale in the format 1:24 which is used in the functions and converted to a decimal fraction.

The code works well initially but then stopped working when I reopened it. If i add a message box after the calculate. I had the same issue with using `SelectionChange` for the worksheet. Thoughts? Here is the code that I used.

Also I am using a formatted table which is what is not updating.

```
Private Sub ScaleBox_Change()
    Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Private Sub ScaleBox_Change()
    Applicatin.CalculateFull '<<< edit
End Sub
```

If that doesn't do it then it would help to post your formulas.

Comment: Tried this and got run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Try my edit - I forgot it's not a range/sheet method

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler `ScaleBox_Change` does not make any changes to the worksheet, so any calculation will be working on the old data.

To fix this, place the result from the `ScaleBox` and place it in the worksheet in the appropriate place (and in the right format for what you are trying to do). Then do the calculate routine.

Comment: I could do that but I want to maintain the reference to the scalebox rather than a linked cell. When the calculate command is first entered it works perfectly but when i save and reopen, it no longer works.

Comment: @Cassidy: Your calculations are done in the worksheet, so you must change the values in the worksheet. The reference to the `scalebox` only exist within the scope of the form. You can also an include a `ScaleBox_Enter` or `_GetFocus` event so that you can check your relevant value in the worksheet against what you have in the form.